# can any one explain meaning of mixed and buffer data type in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

can any one explain meaning of mixed and buffer data type in mongoose ?

what is the exact use of mixed datatype in mongoose .Is there any way to store log data(containing both string and number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Mongoose MIX schema type**

An "anything goes" SchemaType, its flexibility comes at a trade-off of it being harder to maintain. Mixed is available either through Schema.Types.Mixed or by passing an empty object literal. The following are equivalent:

```
var Any = new Schema({ any: {} });
var Any = new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed });
```

Since it is a schema-less type, you can change the value to anything else you like, but Mongoose loses the ability to auto detect/save those changes. To "tell" Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has changed, call the .markModified(path) method of the document passing the path to the Mixed type you just changed.

```
person.anything = { x: [3, 4, { y: "changed" }] };
person.markModified('anything');
person.save(); // anything will now get saved
```

(original content taken from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified)

**Mongoose Buffer Schema type**

Buffer type is used when you usually work with items that get saved in binary form, a good example would be images.